# Why does the ring of entire functions have no zero divisors?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Why does the ring of entire functions have no zero divisors, while the ring of infinitely differentiable functions on the real line does?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** An entire function whose zero set has an accumulation point is the zero function.

Comment: By contrast, the differentiability condition on real functions is insufficiently strong to ensure that an infinitely differentiable function for which derivatives of all orders vanish at a point is constant on an interval containing that point.

Comment: Yes, exactly; in the real case the appropriate replacement is the ring of real-analytic functions. The difference between these cases is a consequence of the remarkable fact that in the complex setting differentiability implies analyticity, whereas in the real case even smoothness (infinite differentiability) does not imply real-analyticity.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would kindly explain their objection?

Answer (score 2):

Let $fg\equiv0$ which $f$ and $g$ are entire function. If $f(z)\neq 0$ for some $z\in \mathbb C$, then $f$ for some $\delta \gt0$ be non-zero in $D(\delta,z)$.  every point of $D(\delta,z)$ is a limit point of $D(\delta,z)$ and from the identity $fg\equiv0$ we shod have $g(z)=0$ for every $z\in D(\delta,z)$. It's mean that the zero point of $g$ in $D(\delta,z)$ has limit point. So by the identity theorem, $g\equiv0$.